# What is/causes this 3D dust structure?

Tags: electrostatics, structure-formation

I was recently on a flight and noticed some strange objects located inside the plane window. To me, it looks like dust which has arranged itself into a complex hydrocarbon-like structure, with filaments forming into pentagons about 1 mm across. It looks like there are smaller elements of the same material scattered around the larger structures.

I noticed similar structures in the window behind me, but couldn't check any other windows to see if they were also there. The plane was a Boeing 717-200, and the two windows I could check were level with the front of the engines.

The photo below shows the structures in question with an Australian 10 cent coin (23.60 mm diameter) for scale.

What is this substance? Why does it form this kind of structure?

[image: Photo of small dust-like structures inside an aeroplane window]

Comment: Looks like it might be crumbs from some low-density foam gasket.